# Как правильно организовать таблицы в БД. Где есть динамические колонки на основе второй таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть первая таблица она основная. Поля. id,author, title, desc, price.
Есть потребность в добавлении в эту таблицу доп полей, но добавление будет происходить с админки, и их количество заранее неизвестно.
Причем у каждого доп поля может быть глобальный флаг типа, показывать или нет.

Я думал сделать вторую таблицу, куда буду вносить дополнительные поля.
Допустим id, title, value. 
И добавляем сюда к примеру. 2 доп поля. На складе, у поставщика.

ПО итогу хочу получить таблицу вида: ID, AUTHOR, TITLE, DESC, PRICE, "На складе", "У поставщика".

Вообще подскажите в какую сторону смотреть, куда копать, или как правильнее организовать это все, чтобы былу удобная возможность по выборке.

Comment: Смотря чего и как выбирать. Обычно это делается в структуре типа EAV (гуглить и искать на этом сайте прямо по этим буквам).

Comment: Также ознакомьтесь с типом поля [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), может подойдет. И вообще, посмотрите в сторону NoSQL баз, Mongo в частности. Можно почитать теорию EAV, потом сделать свою структуру таблиц и написать обслуживающий код. А можно просто научиться работать с Монго и не городить этот огород. Хотя, кому как

Comment: Спасибо большое,буду читать EAV. А Монго изучу обязательно на будущие проекты.